# Error using SQLite ATTACH - DETACH in Delphi

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I experience a, for me unsolvable, problem with ATTACH and DETACH in SQLite, using Delphi (Firedac).

I have one database file connected and attach a second one with:

```
FDConnection1.ExecSQL('ATTACH DATABASE "' + Import_DB_filename + '" AS IMPORTDB;');
```

Therein, the variable 'Import_DB_filename' contains the full path and filename of the database file.

This works OK and I can access both databases within the connection through the FireDac queries, and can do my coding without problems. 
However, things go wrong upon detaching:

```
FDConnection1.ExecSQL('DETACH DATABASE IMPORTDB;');
```

In debugging mode, I always get the error:

> Debugger Exception Notification
>     E Project My_Program.EXE raised exception class $C0000005 with message    'access violation at 0x00405d7b: read of address 0x00000000'.

Apparently something goes wrong with the memory assignments, since the debugger stops in a (assembly) function `SysFreeMem(P:Pointer): Integer;` in `GETMEM.INC`.

Whatever I try, the error persists and associates a memory leak that eventually leads to a crash of the compiler (Delphi Seattle Enterprise).

Even attaching and subsequent detaching of the database without passing any code results in the same error.

(FDconnection:  locking mode = lmNormal; 
                JournalMode  = jmOff or jmWALL or jmdelete)

I do hope that you can help me out on this lasting problem.

Comment: To be sure: so you already have a proper [Firedac connection set up](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Setting_up_Connections_%28FireDAC%29) and now you want to use the [SQLite ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) to add another database file to the current connection? And please [edit] your question to include the Delphi version.

Comment: Why do you need to use the same FDConnection with both database files?  Why not have a separate connection for each of them.

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure whether I tried this already. I will check it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I want to use a single FDConnection because I copy data from the second database into the existing database by using "insert...select" statements.

Comment: Well, you can do that regardless, if you're generating the Sql statements in code.

Comment: I am doing that at this moment. I change the insert... select into insert.. values, and create a string with values from the second database. It will take me quite some time. But I am sure this cannot be needed. Attaching detaching is just so common!

Comment: Could you also just check that `FDConnection1` does not equal `nil` at the time of the detach-call. Sounds silly, but important to get that out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the project below, you should find that:

- You can access two Sqlite databases quite happily using separate FDConnections and FDTables.
- You can move data from a table in one db to a table of the same name in the other using a FireDAC FDDataMove component.

Code:

```
unit BatchMoveu;

interface

[...]

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    FDConnection1: TFDConnection;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    FDGUIxWaitCursor1: TFDGUIxWaitCursor;
    FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1: TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink;
    Button1: TButton;
    FDTable1: TFDTable;
    FDConnection2: TFDConnection;
    DataSource2: TDataSource;
    DBGrid2: TDBGrid;
    btnBatchMove: TButton;
    FDDataMove1: TFDDataMove;
    FDTable2: TFDTable;
    procedure btnBatchMoveClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure PopulateTable1;
    procedure TestDataMove;
  public
    procedure CreateDatabase(DBName : String; FDConnection : TFDConnection;
      FDTable : TFDTable);
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  DBName1 = 'd:\delphi\code\sqlite\db1.sqlite';
  DBName2 = 'd:\delphi\code\sqlite\db2.sqlite';

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateDatabase(DBName1, FDConnection1, FDTable1);
  CreateDatabase(DBName2, FDConnection2, FDTable2);

  PopulateTable1;

  FDTable2.Open;

end;

procedure TForm3.CreateDatabase(DBName : String; FDConnection : TFDConnection;
  FDTable : TFDTable);
var
  AField : TField;
  i : Integer;
begin
  if FileExists(DBName) then
    DeleteFile(DBName);

  AField := TLargeIntField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldName := 'ID';
  AField.DataSet := FDTable;
  AField.Name := AField.DataSet.Name + 'IDField';

  AField := TWideStringField.Create(Self);
  AField.Size := 80;
  AField.FieldName := 'Name';
  AField.DataSet := FDTable;
  AField.Name := AField.DataSet.Name + 'NameField';

  FDConnection.Params.Values['database'] := DBName;
  FDConnection.Connected:= True;
  FDTable.CreateTable(False, [tpTable]);
end;

procedure TForm3.PopulateTable1;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  FDTable1.Open;

  for i:= 1 to 1000 do begin
    FDTable1.InsertRecord([i, 'Row ' + IntToStr(i)]);
  end;
  FDTable1.Close;
  //FDConnection1.Commit;

  FDTable1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm3.TestDataMove;
var
  Item : TFdMappingItem;
begin
  Item := FDDataMove1.Mappings.Add;
  Item.SourceFieldName := 'ID';
  Item.DestinationFieldName := 'ID';

  Item := FDDataMove1.Mappings.Add;
  Item.SourceFieldName := 'Name';
  Item.DestinationFieldName := 'Name';

  FDDataMove1.Source := FDTable1;
  FDDataMove1.Destination := FDTable2;
  FDDataMove1.Options := FDDataMove1.Options - [poOptimiseSrc];
  FDDataMove1.Execute;

  FDConnection2.Connected := False;
  FDTable2.Open;
end;
procedure TForm3.btnBatchMoveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TestDataMove;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDConnection1.Close;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you MartynA,

Comment: Thank you MartynA, You have convinced me that using two FDConnection components is a good way to circumvent the use of ATTACH and DETACH. I have changed my code accordingly. However, the error persists. Apparently, it had little to do with the attaching but rather something with the memory assignments. I must have screwed it somewhere. Perhaps you can hint me how to address such errors. I have installed MadExcept, but it did not give me any clue. Unfortunately, hexadecimal addresses are like Chinese to me.

Comment: Well, "read of address 0x00000000" suggests that something has not been properly initialised, maybe a Delphi object which is being accessed before .Create() has been called on it.  Make sure you have "Use debug DCUs" turned in in your project options, then do a project build and run.  When the error occurs, in the IDE go to **View | Debug windows | Call Stack** and you should then be able to look down the stack and see where the exception is occurring.